# Find matching value in query based on text

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

I am building a table in power query and I want to find the matching value from a column in a row. Does anyone know how to do this? I import my source data with:

```
leagueDataSource = #"League Data All",
```

this gives me this table:

[image: table]

I then have a variable called:

```
leagueName = "Albania - Superliga",
```

and want to create another variable called activeSeason. How do I match the variable leagueName with the value in active Season ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer myself :)

```
leagueName = "name",
a = List.PositionOf(leagueDataSource[League], leagueName, 0),
leagueID = Number.ToText(leagueDataSource[Active Season]{a}),
```